# Onedrive business upload API : A file name with spaces becomes +

Tags: php, onedrive

before upload i will urlencode the filename, so my url is

https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/root:/test+test.txt:/content when i upload a file named test test.txt

but this API isn't deal with this.

onedrive api:
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/root:/test+test.txt:/content can run correctly

how can i keep the accurate file name with PHP

Comment: if i didn't urlencode , my server return 400 Error(Invalid URL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` is a tricky character in so far as being an encoded form of space. I believe it's technically only legal in the query string, and the expected way to encode the space in the path component is using `%20`. You'll get the same behavior from both consumer and business if you use the percent encoded version, while as you've found out the + encoding only works as you desire for consumer (although whether it should is obviously debatable).

Comment: I am in accordance with RFC 3986 standard to encoding url solved this problem

Answer (score -1):

Office is slowly turning into Google Drive's retarded cousin. Sharepoint or Onedrive doesn't accept spaces or other characters.